# Error when opening shapefile

Tags: r, import, shapefile

I am trying to open a shapefile in R, but I am getting the following error message:

```
Error in getinfo.shape(filen) : Error opening SHP file
```

I have checked other responses and most problems seem to have been solved by ensuring that the .dbf and .shx files are in the same folder. I have them all in the same folder (along with some other extensions too) but I still get the error message. I work on a mac.
This is my code:

```
getinfo.shape("/Users/Suz/Desktop/DWH satellite maps/20100517_Composite.shp")
```

I have tried it without the `.shp` extension, and with other commands, such as `readShapePoints` etc. Nothing has worked so far. Please help, I am new to R and making maps, and after extensive Googling and forum-reading I am still stuck.

Comment: Does `readOGR("/Users/Suz/Desktop/DWH satellite maps", "20100517_Composite")` work? (`readOGR` is in the `rgdal` package).

Comment: Also, can you please include in your post the output of `list.files('/Users/Suz/Desktop/DWH satellite maps')`? Secondly, could you please try with a trusted shapefile, e.g. [here](http://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/110m/cultural/ne_110m_admin_1_states_provinces.zip). Finally, are you aware that `getinfo.shape` only reads the header of the shapefile, and doesn't actually read in the data - is that what you intended?

Comment: I tried the shapefile that you suggested:    getinfo.shape("/Users/Suz/Desktop/ne_110m_admin_1_states_provinces.shp") and still got the same error message. I am starting to think that my problem is something stupid and I don't have all the necessary libraries open or something..? I have sp, map tools, rgdal, and rgeos.

Comment: The list.files command gives all the files in the directory (which there are 174 of) so the whole output is huge to post. But my files are there.

Comment: Good to hear. If you can work out what you were doing wrong, please add your solution as an answer and accept it for the benefit of future generations.

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same problem. Often come other files with your SHP-file. If they are missing the file cant be loaded.

So search if there are any other file ext. with "20100517_Composite" at the source you got your file.

Cant comment yet but i wanted the ppl to save time, if this is the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You could try `getinfo.shape(file.choose())` to select the file via a pop up window. If this works then it is probably an issue with your input string.

Note: I'm on linux, but I think `file.choose()` should work for mac.

Answer (score 0):

After having the same issue, I did some digging and found a nice thread [here].[1](http://w3facility.org/question/error-opening-shp-file-in-r-using-maptools-readshapepoly/)
Turns out that after checking the    list.files()    command and found that my files were not there, and
even though I had included the file path in my original code, it still produced the error shown in the question. I then moved all the files into the working directory and then the command below worked.

```
readShapeSpatial()
```

Also simply changing the wd would work as well.

```
setwd("directory_path")
```

I figured I'd put this here as @jbaums suggested because it would have saved me some time in solving this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem until i removed the `.shp` extension.

So instead of

```
readShapeSpatial("/Users/Suz/Desktop/DWH satellite maps/20100517_Composite.shp")
```

go with

```
readShapeSpatial("/Users/Suz/Desktop/DWH satellite maps/20100517_Composite")
```

If you have all the files in the working directory it should work like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way to read a shapefile in R is

either (to get a Spatial*) object

```
library(raster)
x <- shapefile("/Users/Suz/Desktop/DWH satellite maps/20100517_Composite.shp")
```

or (to get a sf object)

```
library(sf)
st_read("/Users/Suz/Desktop/DWH satellite maps/20100517_Composite.shp")
```

(but do *not* use the deprecated (incomplete and obsolete) function `readShapeSpatial`)

In action:

```
library(raster)
library(sf)

f <- system.file("external/lux.shp", package="raster")
s1 <- shapefile(f) 
s2 <- st_read(f)
```

If this does not work, you need to check if your file exists:

```
file.exists(f)
```

To get a list of shapefiles in a directory, you can do

```
path <- "c:/temp"  # change with your directory name
ff <- list.files(path, pattern='\\.shp$', full.names=TRUE)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is still a problem. I solve it more directly calling the `shapefile` using `file.choose()` and manually selecting the file. Hope this helps for anyone.

```
library (rgdal)
a = readOGR (file.choose()) #then selecting the shape file manually
```