# readOGR() cannot open file

Tags: r, gdal, rgdal, ogr

```
wmap <- readOGR(dsn="~/R/funwithR/data/ne_110m_land", layer="ne_110m_land")
```

This code is not loading the shape file and error is generated as

```
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
Cannot open file
```

I am sure that the directory is correct one. At the end / is also not there and layer name is also correct.

Inside the ne_110m_land directory files I have are:

```
ne_110m_land.dbf
ne_110m_land.prj
ne_110m_land.shp
ne_110m_land.shx
ne_110m_land.VERSION.txt
ne_110m_land.README.html
```

Answer (score 66, accepted):

You could have shown that you have the right path with:

```
list.files('~/R/funwithR/data/ne_110m_land', pattern='\\.shp$')
file.exists('~/R/funwithR/data/ne_110m_land/ne_110m_land.shp')
```

perhaps try:

```
readOGR(dsn=path.expand("~/R/funwithR/data/ne_110m_land"), layer="ne_110m_land")
```

or a simpler alternative that is wrapped around that:

```
library(raster)
s <- shapefile("~/R/funwithR/data/ne_110m_land/ne_110m_land.shp")
```

**Update:**

`rgdal` has changed a bit and you do not need to separate the path and layer anymore (at least for some formats). So you can do

```
x <- readOGR("~/R/funwithR/data/ne_110m_land/ne_110m_land.shp")
```

(perhaps still using path.expand)

Also, if you are still using `readOGR` you are a bit behind the times. It is better to use `terra::vect` or `sf::st_read`.

Comment: thanks! path.expand() worked. Sorry that I can't vote up the answer.

Comment: @RiteshJungThapa you can accept this as the correct answer (even if you can't upvote)

Comment: Why is the code posted in the question not working? I have the same issue but multiple files with same name and different extension in the folder, thus `path.expand` won't work.

Comment: It does not work because readOGR does not use `path.expand` because it does not know if the first argument actually is a file path (it could be a database). There is no reason why this should not work for you.

Comment: In my case the codes above work only if I add the absolute path . with relative path the same error occurs

Answer (score 13):

I had the same error. To read in a shapefile, you need to have three files in your folder: the .shp, .dbf and .shx files.

Comment: I was having the same problem as OP and this cut right to the issue.

Answer (score 8):

For me, the command returned the `Cannot open layer` error when I included the `dsn` and `layer` tags.

So when I included it all just as 
`readOGR('~/R/funwithR/data/ne_110m_land/ne_110m_land.shp')`
it worked.

Note that my file was a gjson, so I've only seen this with
`readOGR('~/R/funwithR/data/ne_110m_land/ne_110m_land.gjson')`

Answer (score 2):

the Mandatory files should be all in the same directory

.shp — shape format

.shx — shape index format;

.dbf — attribute format;

then we can just give the path as a parameter to the function it will work.

```
global_24h =readOGR( '/Users/m-store/Desktop/R_Programing/global_24h.shp')
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 1):

Here's what worked for me (with a real example)

```
require(rgdal)
shape <- readOGR(dsn = "1259030001_ste11aaust_shape/STE11aAust.shp", layer = "STE11aAust")
```

The exact data is available [here](http://www.abs.gov.au/AUSSTATS/abs@.nsf/DetailsPage/1259.0.30.001July%202011?OpenDocument) (download the .zip file called 'State and Territory ASGC Ed 2011 Digital Boundaries in MapInfo Interchange Format')

Answer (score 1):

the syntax: library(raster)
`s <- shapefile("~/R/funwithR/data/ne_110m_land/ne_110m_land.shp")` worked perfectly! todah rabah!

Answer (score 0):

As I commented in other post ([Error when opening shapefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21614443/error-when-opening-shapefile/41105314#41105314)), using file.choose() and selecting manually will help in the case one file selection is needed. Apparently is related with NaturalEarth shapefiles

Answer (score 0):

it seems to me that this is the solution, at least before uploading it to the cloud

```
  ######################################
  #             Server
  ######################################
  #I tell R where to extract the data from
  #Le digo al R donde debe jalar la data

  dirmapas <- "E:/Tu-carpeta/Tu-sub-carpeta/ESRI" #Depende donde tengas tú tus 
                                                  #archivos de cartografía 

  setwd(dirmapas)

  #The raw map
  # El mapa de polígonos en blanco y negro
  departamentos<-readOGR(dsn="BAS_LIM_DEPARTAMENTO.shp", layer="BAS_LIM_DEPARTAMENTO")
```