# R: readOGR() cannot open file

Tags: r, rgdal

I downloaded a SHAPE file from [here](https://borders.ukdataservice.ac.uk/easy_download_data.html?data=England_gor_2011). I added to my working directory:

```
> list.files('/home/lucho/data/EnglandGIS/', pattern='\\.shp$')
[1] "england_gor_2011.shp"
> file.exists('/home/lucho/data/EnglandGIS/england_gor_2011.shp')
[1] TRUE
```

However, I cannot read it:

```
library("rgdal")
shape <- readOGR(dsn = path.expand("/home/lucho/data/EnglandGIS/england_gor_2011"), layer = "england_gor_2011")
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open file
```

The [only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30561889/readogr-cannot-open-file?noredirect=1&lq=1) other similar question with accepted answer is of not help. What is the problem? Is the data corrupted? How can I tell? (if you could download the data and try it yourself, that might be the best way)

I am using latest R with latest Rstudio, in Ubuntu 16.04.

Comment: I think you need `dsn = path.expand("/home/lucho/data/EnglandGIS")`, this is just the folder containing the files, not the layer name (which goes in the `layer` argument). Alternatively, you can use "/home/lucho/data/EnglandGIS/england_gor_2011.shp" and get rid of the `layer` argument altogether

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To import shape files with `readOGR` you can either use

```
readOGR(dsn = "/home/lucho/data/EnglandGIS/", layer = "england_gor_2011")
```

where `dsn` is the folder containing `england_gor_2011.shp` (and other files with the same name but different extensions, e.g. `england_gor_2011.dbf`, etc.) or you can specify the full path to the shape file (including the extension):

```
readOGR("/home/lucho/data/EnglandGIS/england_gor_2011.shp")
```

The second method won't work for earlier versions of `rgdal` as far as I remember.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to specifiy the extension of the shape file in the `readOGR` command:

```
library("rgdal")
shape <- readOGR(dsn = path.expand("england_gor_2011.shp"), 
                layer = "england_gor_2011")

#############
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: "england_gor_2011.shp", layer: "england_gor_2011"
with 9 features
It has 3 fields
```

Hope this can help you.

Answer (score 1):

Although this question seems to be answered, here are a couple of other options on how to read in the shapefile:

you can also try the function `shapefile` from the `raster`package:

```
library(raster)
shp <- shapefile("/home/lucho/data/EnglandGIS/england_gor_2011.shp")
```

or the function `st_read` from the new `sf`package (very efficient):

```
library(sf)
shp <- st_read(system.file("/home/lucho/data/EnglandGIS/england_gor_2011.shp", package="sf"))
```