# Cannot open OGR file

Tags: r, shapefile, ogr

I have already tried re-writing this code using `dsn=path.expand` and shapefile. However, this keeps giving me an error.

```
mapfile <-readOGR("/Users/kajoribanerjee/Documents/PhD/bayesian geoadditive model/india_2011.shp")
```

> Error in ogrListLayers(dsn = dsn) : Cannot open data source}

Comment: try `readOGR("/Users/kajoribanerjee/Documents/PhD/bayesian geoadditive model", "india_2011")`

Answer (score 0):

In `rgdal` you have to name a layer destination (`dsn`) and a layer name (`layer`).
In case of a shapefile located at `/home/user/folder/shapefile.shp` that would be `dsn = "/home/user/folder"` and `layer = "shapefile"`

So you should use it like this:

```
mapfile <- readOGR("/Users/kajoribanerjee/Documents/PhD/bayesian geoadditive model", 
                   "india_2011")
```

You should also have a look at [`?readOGR`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rgdal/versions/1.2-16/topics/readOGR) where it is stated that:

> If reading a shapefile, the data source name (`dsn`= argument) is the folder (directory) where the shapefile is, and the layer is the name of the shapefile (without the .shp extension)

Another way is shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30562015/3250126) by using `raster::shapefile`.