# Cannot open shp file

Tags: r, shapefile

I'm trying to read a shp file but to no success. I already tried all the answers in this [readOGR() cannot open file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30561889/readogr-cannot-open-file) and none of them worked for me.

Using

```
file.exists('../Downloads/NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4326_LEVL_2.shp')
```

I get back TRUE

But when I run

```
shapefile('../Downloads/NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4326_LEVL_2.shp')
```

I get

```
Error: file.exists(extension(x, ".shp")) is not TRUE
```

I tried running

```
readOGR(dsn = "..Downloads/NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4326_LEVL_2.shp", layer ="NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4326_LEVL_2")
```

and get the error

```
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open data source
```

Also tried

```
readOGR(dsn=path.expand("../Downloads"), layer="NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4326_LEVL_2")
```

and got

```
Error in ogrInfo(dsn = dsn, layer = layer, encoding = encoding, use_iconv = use_iconv,  : 
  Cannot open layer
```

I don´t know what else to try

Comment: Most likely explanation: `"..Downloads/NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4326_LEVL_2.shp"` is a folder rather than a file.  Let me know if this is the correct explanation, if so I'll add this as an answer

Comment: Does this help? [Things I Forget: Reading a Shapefile in R with readOGR](https://landeco2point0.wordpress.com/2013/09/27/things-i-forget-reading-a-shapefile-in-r-with-readogr/). The first argument should be a directory and the layer argument is the file minus the `.shp` extension.

Comment: It is a file, and I tried using "." in the dsn but still got the same error. Also tried to load other shp files to see if the problem was with the one I had, but no results

Comment: What we have here is an issue specific to your local system. Is there a folder in `Downloads` which contains the `.shp` file and other files? Then the path to that folder, minus the trailing slash is the `dsn`. The shapefile name, without its extension, is the `layer`. Specify the arguments correctly and it will work. What you seem to be doing is trying multiple combinations of things in the hope that one will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was facing the same issue, but got around it when I put other files that were in the same .zip file as my .shp file together with it in the working directory. Files with extensions such as .shx, .qpg, .prj and .cpj. I didn't change anything in the code. Just added the files.

Answer (score 0):

All options tried so far were slightly wrong :)

Assuming you downloaded the ZIP file [from here](https://ec.europa.eu/eurostat/cache/GISCO/distribution/v1/nuts-2013.html) and extracted it in `Downloads`, then the path to the file should be:

```
Downloads/NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4326_LEVL_2.shp/NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4326_LEVL_2.shp
```

Note that both the unzipped directory and the file inside it have the `.shp` extension.

The dsn should be the path to the directory without a trailing slash and the layer is the shapefile without the `.shp` extension.

So I think you want:

```
readOGR("../../Downloads/NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4326_LEVL_2.shp", "NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4326_LEVL_2")
```

**EDIT:**

I ran this code on my local (Windows 10) machine:

```
nuts <- readOGR("../../Downloads/NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4326_LEVL_2.shp",
                "NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4326_LEVL_2")
```

and the file reads, with message:

```
OGR data source with driver: ESRI Shapefile 
Source: "C:\Users\nsaunders8\Downloads\NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4326_LEVL_2.shp", 
  layer: "NUTS_RG_03M_2013_4326_LEVL_2"
with 320 features
It has 5 fields
```

Comment: It didnt work :( I trid putting the files in other directorys, but still geting the "cannot open data source" error. I have no ideia what the problem is, because I tried using with other shp files, and nothing works

Comment: If the files and directories on your system are as specified in the answer, it will work. If you are essentially just trying random combinations of things, it will not work. Read the link in my comment, compare with your situation and try again.

Comment: I tried already. I put the file in my working directory, and used readOGR(".","nameofile") and gave me the "Cannot open layer" error. What i find it weird is that when I run list.file, the file is there (and the only one with that name) and file.exists gives me TRUE

Comment: Don't put the file in your working directory. Download the `.zip` to `Downloads`. Unzip it. Run the code with the correct specification for `dsn` and `layer`, as described in the answer.