# R shiny webapp - webapp runs & works locally but returns error when running app or deploying app to rshiny

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

This is my code. I am trying to create an interactive webapp where the user can add new data by drawing polygons and then the
I don't understand the error it returns when trying to click 'Run App' in RSTudio or deploy the app to shinyapps (as it works locally when I just run the code). Does someone have an idea why it doesn't work when running or deploying?

```
## install required packages (if not installed yet)
require(class)
require(dplyr)
require(leafem)
require(leaflet)
require(leaflet.extras)
require(raster)
require(rgdal)
require(rsconnect)
require(sf)
require(sp)
require(shiny) 

#### 0. Import Data ####

## import landfills clusters spatial data (point data)
landfills_clusters <- readOGR("plasticleakagewebapp/data/landfill_clusters.gpkg")
landfills_clusters_sf <- st_read('plasticleakagewebapp/data/landfill_clusters.gpkg')

### import landfill polygons
landfills_polygons <- readOGR("plasticleakagewebapp/data/landfills/OpenLandfills_Vietnam.shp", use_iconv = T, encoding = "UTF-8")

## import shapefile of vietnam
vietnam <- readOGR("plasticleakagewebapp/data/vietnam/vietnam.shp")



#### 1. Interactive Map (Leaflet) ####

## plot map with landfills colored by cluster
# e.g. plot water distance < 500m in red

# create color palette
cof <- colorFactor(c("green","blue","red"), domain = c("1","2","3"))

map <- leaflet(landfills_clusters_sf) %>%
    addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldImagery) %>% 
    setView(lng = 105.48, lat = 15.54, zoom = 6) %>%
    addMiniMap %>%
    addPolygons(data = vietnam, fill = F, weight = 2, color = "#FFFFCC", group = "Outline") %>%
    addPolygons(data = landfills_polygons, fill = F, weight = 2, color = "#FFFFCC") %>%
    addCircleMarkers(data = landfills_clusters_sf, color = ~cof(km_cluster_unstand), radius = sqrt(landfills_clusters_sf$area_ha)*2, 
                     fillOpacity = 0.5, label = ~name, group = "Risk") %>%
    addLegend("bottomleft", colors= c("red","blue","green"), labels=c("high", "medium", "low"), title = "Leakage Risk")
map



#### Interactive Map ####
ui_inter <- fluidPage("Classification the Plastic Leakage Risk of Landfills in Vietnam", id = "nav",
                      
  tabPanel("Interactive Map",
   div(class = "outer",
       
       # If not using custom CSS, set height of leafletOutput to a number instead of percent
       leafletOutput("map", width = "1700px", height = "800px"),
       
       absolutePanel(id = "controls", class = "panel panel-default", fixed = T,
         draggable = T, top = 60, left = "auto", right = 20, bottom = "auto",
         width = 350, height = "auto",
         
         h2("Plastic Leakage Risk"),
         
         plotOutput("histRain", height = 200),
         plotOutput("histWind", height = 200),
       ),
   )
),
tabPanel("Data Explorer",
   hr(),
   
   # display the data in an interactive table
   DT::dataTableOutput("landfills"),
   textInput('Long', 'Enter new landfill longitude'),
   textInput('Lat', 'Enter new landfill latitude'),
   actionButton("update", "Update Table")
  )
)


df <- landfills_clusters_sf[-c(2,9:10,12,16:17)] # select relevant columns

## add long & lat coordinates
df$long <- st_coordinates(landfills_clusters_sf)[,1]
df$lat <- st_coordinates(landfills_clusters_sf)[,2]


server_inter <- function(input, output, session) {
    
    ## create interactive map with leaflet
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        map %>%
            # add toolbox to draw polygons
            addDrawToolbar(
                targetGroup = "drawnPoly", 
                rectangleOptions = F, 
                polylineOptions = F, 
                markerOptions = F, 
                editOptions = editToolbarOptions(selectedPathOptions = selectedPathOptions()), 
                circleOptions = F,
                circleMarkerOptions = F,
                polygonOptions = drawPolygonOptions(showArea = T, repeatMode = F, shapeOptions = 
                                                        drawShapeOptions(fillColor = "orange", clickable = T))) %>%
            addStyleEditor()
    })
    
    latlongs <- reactiveValues() # temporary to hold coords
    latlongs$df2 <- data.frame(Longitude = numeric(0), Latitude = numeric(0))
    
    
    ## create empty reactive spdf to store drawn polygons
    value <- reactiveValues()
    value$drawnPoly <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(SpatialPolygons(list()), data = data.frame(notes=character(0), stringsAsFactors = F))
    
    # fix the polygon to start another
    observeEvent(input$map_draw_new_feature, {
        
        coor <- unlist(input$map_draw_new_feature$geometry$coordinates)
        
        Longitude <- coor[seq(1,length(coor), 2)] 
        Latitude <- coor[seq(2,length(coor), 2)]
        
        isolate(latlongs$df2 <- rbind(latlongs$df2, cbind(Longitude, Latitude)))
        
        poly <- Polygon(cbind(latlongs$df2$Longitude, latlongs$df2$Latitude))
        polys <- Polygons(list(poly), ID = input$map_draw_new_feature$properties$`_leaflet_id`)
        spPolys <- SpatialPolygons(list(polys))
        print(spPolys)
        
        value$drawnPoly <- rbind(value$drawnPoly, SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(spPolys, data = data.frame(notes = NA, row.names = row.names(spPolys))))
        
        ## add polygons to landfills polygons df
        test <- SpatialPolygonsDataFrame(spPolys, data = data.frame(name = 1:length(spPolys), row.names = row.names(spPolys)))
        test@data$area <- NA
        test@data$Notes <- NA
        test@data$location <- NA
        test@proj4string <- CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs")
        
        new_polygons <- rbind(landfills_polygons, test)
        
        ## export new & old landfills to shapefile 
        shapefile(x = new_polygons, filename = "plasticleakagewebapp/data/landfill/OpenLandfills_Vietnam_total.shp", overwrite = T)
        
        shapefile(x = test, filename = "plasticleakagewebapp/data/landfills/OpenLandfills_Vietnam_new.shp", overwrite = T)
        
        ## run DataPreparation script to calculate data of new landfill
        source("plasticleakagewebapp/plasticleakage_datapreparation.R")
        
        ## import outcome of script
        variables <- readOGR("plasticleakagewebapp/data/landfill_variables.gpkg")
        
        # basic landfills as training data
        train <- landfills_clusters@data[,c(7:8,11,13:15)]
        
        # newly created landfills (from webapp) as testing data
        test <- variables@data[,c(7:8,11,13:14)]
        
        # predict risk class/cluster of new landfill (without re-running clustering algorithm)
        knnClust <- class::knn(train = train[,-6], test = test, k = 1, cl = train$km_cluster_unstand)
        knnClust
        
        ## add cluster as row
        variables$km_cluster_unstand <- knnClust
        
        # drop not needed columns
        landfills_clusters$risk <- NULL
        landfills_clusters$risk_label <- NULL
        
        # combine all landfills into one spdf
        new_variables <- rbind(landfills_clusters, variables)
        
        ## save results as shapefile
        st_write(st_as_sf(new_variables), "plasticleakagewebapp/landfill_clusters_total.gpkg", overwrite = T, append = F)
        
        
        ## update plot upon ending draw
        observeEvent(input$map_draw_stop, {
            
            #replot it - take off the DrawToolbar to clear the features and add it back and use the values from the SPDF to plot the polygons
            leafletProxy('map') %>% 
                removeDrawToolbar(clearFeatures = T) %>% removeShape('temp') %>% clearGroup('drawnPoly') %>% 
                addPolygons(data = value$drawnPoly, group = 'drawnPoly', color = "blue", layerId = row.names(value$drawnPoly)) %>% 
                addDrawToolbar(
                    targetGroup = "drawnPoly", 
                    rectangleOptions = F, 
                    polylineOptions = F, 
                    markerOptions = F, 
                    editOptions = editToolbarOptions(selectedPathOptions = selectedPathOptions()), 
                    circleOptions = F,
                    polygonOptions=drawPolygonOptions(showArea = T, repeatMode = F, shapeOptions
                                                      = drawShapeOptions(fillColor = "orange", clickable = T)))
        })
        
        latlongs$df2 <- data.frame(Longitude = numeric(0), Latitude = numeric(0)) # clear df
        
        ## plot newly added landfills & risk cluster
        leafletProxy("map", session) %>%
            #addPolygons(data = landfills_polygons, fill = F, weight = 2, color = "#FFFFCC") %>%
            addCircleMarkers(data = variables, color = ~cof(km_cluster_unstand), radius = sqrt(variables$area_ha)*2,
                             fillOpacity = 0.5, label = ~name, group = "Risk")
    })
    
    # create object for clicked marker (=landfill)
    observeEvent(input$map_marker_click,{
        ## click returns clickid, long & lat
        click <- input$map_marker_click
        # if(is.null(click))
        #   return()
        leafletProxy("map", session) %>% setView(lng = click$lng, lat = click$lat, zoom = 16)
    })
    
    # A reactive expression that returns the set of landfills that are in map bounds (to plot reactive graphs)
    landfillsInBounds <- reactive({
        if (is.null(input$map_bounds))
            return(landfills_clusters_sf[FALSE,])
        bounds <- input$map_bounds
        latRng <- range(bounds$north, bounds$south)
        lngRng <- range(bounds$east, bounds$west)
        
        subset(landfills_clusters_sf,
               st_coordinates(landfills_clusters_sf)[,2] >= latRng[1] & st_coordinates(landfills_clusters_sf)[,2] <= latRng[2] &
                   st_coordinates(landfills_clusters_sf)[,1] >= lngRng[1] & st_coordinates(landfills_clusters_sf)[,1] <= lngRng[2])
    })
    
    output$histRain <- renderPlot({
        # If no zipcodes are in view, don't plot
        if (nrow(landfillsInBounds()) == 0)
            return(NULL)
        hist(landfillsInBounds()$rain,
             main = "Weather Data",
             xlab = "Average Precipitation (mm)",
             xlim = range(landfills_clusters_sf$rain),
             col = '#00ffff',
             border = 'white')
    })
    
    output$histWind <- renderPlot({
        # If no landfills are in view, don't plot
        if (nrow(landfillsInBounds()) == 0)
            return(NULL)
        hist(landfillsInBounds()$windspeed,
             main = "",
             xlab = "Average Wind Speed (km/h)",
             xlim = range(landfills_clusters_sf$windspeed),
             col = '#00DD00',
             border = 'white')
    })
    
    output$landfills <- DT::renderDT({
        df
    })
}  

# Run the app
shinyApp(ui_inter, server_inter)
```

Error which is returend when clicking "Run App" in RStudio:
Fehler in ogrListLayers(dsn = dsn) : Cannot open data source

Comment: Welcome to SO! Sadly, that’s hardly a _minimal_ reproducible example…

Comment: true, but I'm quite frustrated at this point

Comment: Without actually running your example... in my experience it's usually an in issue of package dependencies not available on the server. With RSConnect it's usually OK, but worth checking. Also if the server is linux and you're in windows, you can get weird things like paths being case sensitive or line ending characters being different.

Comment: Perhaps [this answer helps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30561889/readogr-cannot-open-file/30562015#30562015).